# CodeIgniter 3 on remote server issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, apache2.2

I am trying to setup a production server with a codeIgniter project.
All my `http` request redirects to homepage that `login` page.
I have followed a few instructions from StackOverflow but in vain
Following is my `config.php` settings

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://XXXXX.local/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

The `.htaccess` settings

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And my `sites-enabled` config in apache2 sites-enabled settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    XXXXX.local
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xxx/index.php"
    <directory "/var/www/html/xxx/index.php">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For e.g. if I open on browser `http://XXXXX.local/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js`, it opens  homepage

Also my session does not work, it prints empty..I'm setting like
`$this->session->set_userdata('test','hellow world');`
 Here's my configuration

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Please help!

Comment: _"All my http request redirects to homepage that login page."_ - I have no idea what that means. Can you clarify the issue with some examples?

Comment: e.g.: if I open on browser `http://XXXXX.local/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js`, it opens  homepage
@MagnusEriksson

Comment: Your Apache config is wrong. The document root should be a folder, not a file. Change `"/var/www/html/xxx/index.php"` to `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xxx"` in both places.

Comment: I also don't see the purpose of this line: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)` in your htaccess?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You're right, please write an answer and I can accept it

Comment: Also my session does not work, it prints empty..I'm setting like
`$this->session->set_userdata('test','hellow world');`
 Here's my configuration
`
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
`

Comment: That's another issue and should be posted as a new question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973842/session-not-working-on-codeigniter
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document root in your Apache config needs to be a folder, not a file.

Change

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xxx/index.php"
<directory "/var/www/html/xxx/index.php">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xxx"
<directory "/var/www/html/xxx">
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after you've updated the config.