# Session not working on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, session-variables, codeigniter-3

Hi guys my session is not working on CodeIgniter, please help.. Following is my config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I am setting like as follows

```
$this->session->set_userdata('test', "Hello world!");
```

And trying to retrieve as follows and it prints empty

```
$this->session->userdata('test')
```

Printing all the session

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

prints

```
array(1) {
  ["session_id"]=>
  string(32) "968esdf9539d0bdc29faeb48ad86948"}
```

I have gone through https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-325982.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with CodeIgniter itself
Replace the `system` folder with the latest version of codeIgniter and it started working, replace with version `3.1.0` . I was using `3.0`

Comment: same happend to me once, i updated CI version to the latest

Comment: @Ezekiel 3.0 earlier